# searching a database javascript

Tags: javascript

I have got rid of all syntax errors, but I am unable to retrieve any of the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated. the db variable stores an array of videos that I am looking for and it is a separate js file.

database

```
                    var db = [
                        "JavaScript Version History|http://http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=3&file=01.html",
                        "JavaScript in the Browser|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=3&file=01.html",
                        "Script Tag|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "JavaScript Syntax|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Data Type Literals|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Strings & HTML Strings|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Numbers|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Arrays|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Objects|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Functions|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Scope|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Loops|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Conditionals|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Typeof|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Timers|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Native Objects|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=02.html",
                        "Debugging Tools|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=03.html",
                        "Firebug|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=03.html",
                        "Error Types|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=03.html",
                        "Closures|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=04.html",
                        "Context|http://wddbs.com/javascript/sfw/online/#p=videos&s=1&file=04.html"
                    ];
```

program

```
(function() {
    console.log("hello");
    // Variable initialization (DO NOT FIX ANY OF THE BELOW VAR's)
    var resultsDIV = document.getElementById("results"),
    searchInput = document.forms[0].search,
    currentSearch = '';

    // Validates search query
    var validate = function(query) {
        console.log("validate");
        // Trim whitespace from start and end of search query
        while (query.charAt(0) === " ") {
            query = query.substring(1, query.length);
        }
        while (query.charAt(query.length - 1) === " ") {
            query = query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
        }
        // Check search length, must have 3 characters
        if (query.length < 3) {
            alert("Your search query is too small, try again.");
        }
        // (DO NOT FIX THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW)
        searchInput.focus();
        console.log("test");
        search(query);

    };

    // Finds search matches
    var search = function(query) {
        console.log("search");

        // split the user's search query string into an array
        var queryArray = query.split(" ");

        // array to store matched results from database.js
        var results = [];
        // loop through each index of db array
        for (var i = 0, j = db.length; i < j; i++) {

            // each db[i] is a single video item, each title ends with a pipe "|"
            // save a lowercase variable of the video title
            var dbTitleEnd = db[i].indexOf('|');
            var dbItems = db[i].toLowerCase().substring(0, dbTitleEnd);
            console.log("end of first loop");
        }
        // loop through the user's search query words
        // save a lowercase variable of the search keyword
        for (var ii = 0, jj = queryArray.length; ii < jj; ii++) {
            var qItem = queryArray[ii].toLowerCase();

            // is the keyword anywhere in the video title?
            // If a match is found, push full db[i] into results array
            var compare = dbitem.indexOf(qItem);
            if (compare !== -1) {
                results = results.push(db[i]);
            }

            results.sort();

            console.log("end of second loop");
        }
    };

    // Check that matches were found, and run output functions

    // Put "No Results" message into page (DO NOT FIX THE HTML VAR NOR THE innerHTML)

    var noMatch = function() {

        var html = '' + '<p>No Results found.</p>' + '<p style="font-size:10px;">Try searching for "JavaScript".  Just an idea.</p>';
        resultsDIV.innerHTML = html;
    };

    // Put matches into page as paragraphs with anchors

    var showMatches = function(results) {
        console.log("4");

        // THE NEXT 4 LINES ARE CORRECT.
        var html = '<p>Results</p>',
        title,
        url;

        // loop through all the results search() function
        for (var i = 0, j = results.length; i < j; i++) {

            // title of video ends with pipe
            // pull the title's string using index numbers
            var titleEnd = results[i].indexOf('|');
            title = results[i].subString(0, titleEnd);

            // pull the video url after the title
            url = results[i].substring(results[i].indexOf('|') + 1, results[i].length);

            // make the video link - THE NEXT LINE IS CORRECT.
            html += '<p><a href=' + url + '>' + title + '</a></p>';

            resultsDIV.innerHTML = html;
            //THIS LINE IS CORRECT.
            }

        if (results.length === 0) {
            noMatch();
        } else {
            showMatches(results);
        }
    };

    /***** start of program *******/
    // The onsubmit event will be reviewed in upcoming Course Material.
    // THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW IS CORRECT
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
        var query = searchInput.value;
        validate(query);

        // return false is needed for most events - this will be reviewed in upcoming course material
        // THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW IS CORRECT
        return false;
    };

})();
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with your code? Which part of what you posted doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Can you post an example of one of your data objects?  No one can help you if they don't know the format of your data.  An "array of videos" is pretty generic.

Comment: Ok I added the db variables. The issue with the program is that I am unable to retrieve any info from the db variable even if I search for the right word.

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? At which point in your code do you get different results than you expect? (also, what's with all the spaces at the beginning of each in line in the first code example? They just make it more difficult to read)

Comment: The program came with many syntax errors. I removed all of those and I am able to to get an alert if the character count on the search is less then three. I am still unable to retrieve any of the videos from the variable db when they are put in the search