# Javascript project searching through a variable array

Tags: javascript

I have posted several times about my issue, but I have put the entire code on fiddle. I am just trying to search through the variable db for any matches. I know there are easier ways to do this, but this is a school project.

Here is the link: jsfiddle.net/PByE2/#&togetherjs=N35plzbb5L

Comment: If you're going to search for key/value pairs it would be better to create an object instead of splitting a pipe.

Comment: Your variable `db` is just an array of strings.  What part of searching through those strings do you not know how to do?  We don't just write your school projects for you, but we will help you if you ask a very specific question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [searching a database javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317409/searching-a-database-javascript)

Comment: The question doesn't become better by reposting it. I recommend to learn [how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820), so that you can set breakpoints and inspect variables. You should be able to narrow down the problem and if you still cannot solve it, ask a new question about that specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awB9k/), we came up with this result

```
(function() {

    var form = document.getElementById("searchwrap"),
        searchField = document.getElementById("search"),
        results = document.getElementById("results");

    function validateQuery(query) {
        // display error message for less than 3 characters
        if (query.trim().length < 3) {
            throw new Error("Your query must be at least 3 characters long");
        }
    }

    function queryConcepts(query) {
        var parts, idx, re;

        for (var i=0; i<db.length; i++) {

            // split the db row on the "|" character
            parts = db[i].split("|");

            // create an index of the data; e.g.,
            // {topic: "Error Types", url: "http://..."}
            idx = {topic: parts[0], url: parts[1]};

            // create a case-insensitive RegExp to test if our query matches the topic
            re = new RegExp(query, "i");

            // perform the check; render the result if we have a match
            if (re.test(idx.topic)) {
                renderResult(idx);
            }
        }
    }

    function renderResult(idx) {
        // build P and A tag
        var p = document.createElement("p"),
            a = document.createElement("a");

        // setup A
        a.href = idx.url;
        a.innerHTML = idx.topic;

        // attach A to P
        p.appendChild(a);

        // attach result to output
        results.appendChild(p);
    }

    function clearResults() {
        // clear all result contents
        results.innerHTML = "";  
    }

    function checkForEmptyResult() {
        // search for results
        var r = results.getElementsByTagName("p");

        // if there are no results, display the "empty result" message
        if (r.length === 0) {
            renderEmptyResult();
        }
    }

    function renderEmptyResult() {
        // display no results found
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = "No results found.";

        // provide a recommended search
        var p2 = document.createElement("p");
        p2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Try searching for "));

        // with a linked search term
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href="#query";
        a.innerHTML = "script";
        a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            searchField.value = "script";
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        p2.appendChild(a);

        // attach text to results section
        results.appendChild(p);
        results.appendChild(p2);
    }

    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        try {
            clearResults();
            validateQuery(searchField.value);
            queryConcepts(searchField.value);
            checkForEmptyResult();
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }

        // don't attempt to submit the form data
        event.preventDefault();
    });

})();
```